# Does the bridge crew on the Enterprise NCC-1701 have the ability to see through the ceiling into space?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

The USS Enterprise NCC-1701 appears to have a clear dome over the bridge:

[image: NCC - 1701]

There is a scene in the pilot that zooms in and peers into the bridge from space:

[image: bridge from space]

Does the crew have the ability to see through the dome into space?

Comment: Isn't that screenshot from the remastered versions?  Sheesh.  First Lucas and the prequel trilogy, now Sternbach and Okuda have done it to the real _Star Trek_.  *Sigh*.

Comment: This is the remastered shot, not the original, but the intent is the same.

Comment: @SteveED - But in the original, it's not clear the intent was that it was an actual see-through dome, as opposed to it just being a type of "iris in" shot (see the "iris" section on [this page](http://classes.yale.edu/film-analysis/htmfiles/editing.htm)) where the iris started out conveniently fitted to the circular top of the ship, just as a clever visual transition that emphasized we were cutting to a scene located inside that section of the ship.

Comment: I never liked the idea of the bridge being right up there, in such a vulnerable position. It belonged smack in the center of the ship, surrounded by as much protection as possible. I'm sure that it was placed where it was simply for the sake of that zoom in shot that we saw in the earliest episodes. I can't think of any other reason.

Comment: I always assumed it was a "cutaway" shot - that the ceiling was opaque.

Comment: I realise this is a very old question, but if the ceiling was transparent they'd be in bright sunlight about half the time whenever they're inside a solar system.

Comment: @SteveED I have the "original" The Cage on VHS, and it also shows the top of the bridge as transparent.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We never see the *complete* bridge ceiling from inside in any episode of TOS.  We see it for the first time in TAS and it is definitely opaque.

It could have been that the producers realized that showing space on the inside ceiling was beyond the FX technology of the time and decided to give up on it after the pilot.

I believe that the pilot episode zoom in may have represented a more symbolic approach showing the audience that the bridge was on top (ie most important part) of the ship.

Comment: Roddenberry rejected TAS as non-canon as soon as they got the go to start on _Star Trek: Phase II_ (which became _Star Trek: The Motion Picture).  When he was offered the chance to do TAS, he thought he'd never have any other chance to do Trek on TV or film, so he took it, but once he got another chance, he basically wiped the slate clean and said TAS never happened.

Comment: Roddenberry accepted TAS as cannon by the 2nd season of TNG, and probably after he realized he could make quite a lot of money off of selling the rights to VHS and disc.

Comment: Personally, I would find a transparent dome above my head in space VERY distracting... and likely disorienting as well. Talk about space-sickness...

Answer (score 17):

No. What you see is a retro filming style. The Dome was opaque.

I've discovered a scene in S03E02 to prove it:
[image: Dome of USS Enterprise NCC-1701 from inside]

Thanks to [@TangoOversway](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/1693/tangooversway) for the screenshot idea.

Comment: Uh, that's the same part of the dome that I show in the screen shots -- the part above the red boarder on the lower ceiling with the lights on it.

Comment: But, it covers a large part of dome & gives a feeling that its really a dome (from interior view).

Comment: No more than shown in the wide shot of the empty bridge.  Both basically come to the limit of the "dome" on the original bridge set.

Comment: The point is to cover upper part of dome.. not surface area!

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that.

Comment: I mean this: The zoomed transparent dome in question came after [this image](http://i.imgur.com/rwnqr.png). In this image, you can see opaque lining just below transparent region. This opaque narrow surface on dome can kick out your screenshots. My screenshot covers upper part of interior dome to remove such issues. So, it provides better clarification.

Comment: Look at the empty bridge shot -- it covers the same distance.  Both go to the top of the set.  (But I repeat myself -- again!)

Comment: I don't know how your distance perception says them same, but I have a trick to make you understand: Just below red border of dome, you can find rectangular black monitor/window on vertical wall. Make its height as standard reference. In your photo, only one unit can be fitted on dome. But, in my photo, more than two units can be fitted behind Kirk's head.

Comment: Proportions and angles make that "trick" invalid.  (Look at the lighting and shadows -- the "dome" sections curve over to horizontal at the top of the wide angle.)  I'm just puzzled that I gave an answer ("No") and present some good pics and it seems necessary to post another answer saying the same thing.

Comment: Explain your 1st sentence.. Even after considering errors due to angles, my photo beats yours by huge gap. And, my trick has to do with proportions..

Comment: For a yes-no type question, are you saying.. there shouldn't be more than two answers? My answer says "No" with different "Whys".. So, you shouldn't be puzzled.

Comment: To Mr. Downvoter: Can you please specify your reasons?

Comment: I like this answer. The o

Comment: I like this answer. The image really makes the dome visible.

Comment: The current picture with Kirk and Spock only show the lower dome.  The upper part of the ship appears to be a multi-layered dome.  Including the [image](http://imgur.com/rwnqr) would clarify, so I recommend adding that to the actual answer.

Comment: It's also possible that the dome has a coverable sunroof (that Pike preferred to keep open but that Kirk liked closed), or that the transparent dome was later retrofit with an opaque dome for some reason (e.g. structural integrity, discouraging spying, etc.).

Answer (score 6):

In "The Cage", there's a shot at the beginning of the episode where the camera comes right through a transparent dome.  It's evident that the Enterprise at least *had* a transparent dome at some point.

Comment: I edited my question to add a picture of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The top dome over the bridge is opaque.  Here are a few screenshots from various episodes to illustrate that.  (By the way, that's an exterior light, not a view of the Bridge.)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: None of your photos display bottom-to-up view of dome..

Comment: @SachinShekhar: While they don't show directly overhead, they do show the dome itself.  And if you look at the models, such as the one linked to, there is a lit area above or overhead, so nothing on the exterior indicates any window, either.

Comment: In real life there was no overhead dome to allow lights to be placed to brighten the set for shooting.  Also, the walls came loose so that if they were filming one wall, the opposite one was pulled away for cameras.

Answer (score 3):

This image from "Is there In Truth No Beauty" appears to show a partial dome.[image]

Answer (score 2):

(yes, this is rather late)

There would, in reality, be zero need to have a transparent ceiling on a starship bridge. The bridge will very likely not be anywhere near the top of the ship in any case - why put your command center and senior personnel in such an obvious, exposed location? One good phaser hit and the ship is decapitated.

Oceangoing vessels, aircraft etc. put the bridge on top so they can see where they are going - ships that rely on sensors (like submarines) don't. A submarine's bridge is in the main pressure hull below the sail, and it's only there because the command officers need quick access to the periscope and occasionally the top of the sail. The latest generation of subs (Virginia class) don't use optical periscopes and the bridge is now more-or-less in the center of the boat on deck 2. Of course, this wasn't the case in 1966 (or even 1987).

Comment: While Starfleet is militarily structured, defense it not their sole purpose. At least equally important are exploration, diplomacy, research... None of the Enterprises were intended as ships of war. First contact becomes way harder if show up with a battle cruiser, with ranking officers hiding deep in the belly of the ship.

Comment: A sub's bridge is *on top of* the sail.  The compartment in the pressure hull with the periscope, chart table, and commanding officer is the _control room_.

Comment: I'll accept that technicality, but no one stays on a sub's top-of-the-sail bridge for any significant length of time. When the dive buzzer goes off, the 1-2 people that can fit up there quickly go below and close the hatch. It has no significant apparatus to operate the vessel. The sub's control room serves the same purpose as the bridge on any other vessel.

Comment: In this case, the Bridge of the Enterprise is indeed on top of the saucer under the dome.

Comment: No, they weren't intended as warships, but every one is capable of stepping up to the plate when needed. If you were captain, would you travel the galaxy with just a thin piece of transparent aluminum between you and the hostilities of nature? ( 10-forward and the cabins with windows can be evacuated easily, the bridge cannot). My point is basically that there are zero reasons to put the bridge of a large spacecraft on the top with a big window. If anyone belongs up there with the dome it would be stellar cartography or the officer's lounge.

Comment: @paul Major Stackings is really right, indeed: In this case the bridge is on top - if it makes sense or not. The bridge of the D-Enterprise could be evacuated as easily as 10 foreward: on the side of the viewsceen there is a turbolift leading directly to the battle-bridge. It is rarely used - yet it is there.

Answer (score 2):

It might not make any sense but the top of the saucer section is where the bridge is located. It may well be that it has the facility to become transparent or opaque at command and may have the facility to cover up with blast shield when needed.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Do you have any evidence to support your answer?

Comment: Another possibility it that it is an upper sensor array there is a similar dome on the very bottom of the saucer section.